# How do i view HTTP request details for potential 404's on an iPhone6

Tags: network, safari, web-browsing

I want to see if there were any invalid gets or posts on page 4 of our multistep flow, specifically any http status code 404's

I figured out a couple of ways to view source but the only way I know how to do view HTTP request details is to wire it into my Macbook Pro. I'd like an option which doesn't require a computer if possible.

Comment: wow. downvotes and close.  Seems like a pretty good question, what's wrong?

Comment: What kind of information are you interested in? In my book "network information" is something like IP address, DNS information etc. But you mention GETs and POSTs so it seems that you are more looking for a HTTP monitor or something similar. Can you clarify?

Comment: "* invalid gets or posts** as indicated, i.e. 404 or 500 status codes

Comment: I'm used to using the network tab in desktop browsers for exactly that kind of information.

Comment: I can actually give a perfect answer to this.

Comment: @emotality The question has been reopened, feel free to give an answer if you are around.

Comment: He got me at "I'd like an option which doesn't require a computer if possible." As far as I know, he needs to proxy to his computer then "filter" and view all the requests from phone to computer to internet. If you need help with this, I can help :)